# Where is the Covenant Box

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, ark-aron-kodesh

I wanted to Know where is the Convenant Box? In Most Holy Place There was Convenant Box but is it still there?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean the "Ark of the Covenant".

See [here](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1777-ark-of-the-covenant#anchor10) for the Jewish Encylopedia version.
There are two opinions, either it was captured and taken to Babylon, ([Yoma 53b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.53b.14-54a.1?lang=bi)) or hidden away in the Temple. The Mishnas in Shekalim are interesting:

> Shekalim 6:  [Mishnah 1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Shekalim.6.1?lang=bi): There were thirteen horn-shaped chests,'
> thirteen tables, and thirteen prostrations in the Temple. Those of the
> House of Rabban Gamaliel and they of the House of R. Chanania the
> Prefect of the priests used to prostrate themselves fourteen times.
> And where was the extra one? '-Opposite the woodstore, for thus was a
> tradition among them from their ancestors that the Ark was hidden
> there.'
>
> [Mishnah  2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Shekalim.6.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): It happened once that a certain priest was occupied and
> noticed that some flooring- was different from the rest. He went and
> was telling it to his fellow, but before he could end the matter his
> soul was departed from him.' And thus they knew definitely that there
> the Ark had been hidden.

Answer (score 1):

From the Rambam (Maimonides) Mishneh Torah or Sefer Yad ha-Hazaka, Hilchot Beit HaBechirah, 4:11:

"The Ark was placed on a stone in the western portion of the Holy of Holies.nThe vial of manna and Aharon's staff were placed before it.

When Solomon built the Temple,he was aware that it would ultimately be destroyed. [Therefore,] he constructed a chamber, in which the ark could be entombed below [the Temple building] in deep, maze-like vaults.

King Josiah commanded that [the Ark] be entombed in the chamber built by Solomon, as it is said (II Chronicles 35:3): "And he said to the Levites who would teach wisdom to all of Israel: 'Place the Holy Ark in the chamber built by Solomon, the son of David, King of Israel. You will no [longer] carry it on your shoulders. Now, serve the Lord, your God.'

When it was entombed, Aharon's staff, the vial of manna, and the oil used for anointing were entombed with it. All these [sacred articles] did not return in the Second Temple."

Comment: This translation is from Chabad.org (https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1007197/jewish/Beit-Habechirah-Chapter-4.htm) and there is an interesting footnote on that page that adds more details...

Comment: Here is the footnote: The entombment of the Ark is the subject of a debate among the Sages in the Talmud (Yoma 53b) and the Tosafta (Sotah 13:2). Although some Sages agree that the Ark was entombed as explained above, others maintain that it was one of the sacred articles plundered by the Babylonian conquerors. A third opinion agrees that it was entombed, but argues that it was entombed under the Chamber of Wood in the Woman's Courtyard and not under the Holy of Holies.